# Feeding a single image into model trained with inception v3

Tags: tensorflow

I've searched around the internet for a few days and cannot seem to find an example of someone feeding a single image into a graph created using inception. Please let me know if I have grossly overlooked something obvious. To but the problem in context, I've

1) Trained a model and produced the relevant checkpoint files

```
model.ckpt-10000.data-00000-of-00001 
model.ckpt-10000.index
model.ckpt-10000.meta
```

2) I then load the model

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(checkpoint_path + "/model.ckpt-10000.meta", clear_devices=True)
#<tensorflow.python.training.saver.Saver object at 0x11eea89e8>
sess.run(saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path + "/model.ckpt-10000"))
```

3) This works correctly, so I load the default graph,

```
 graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

Here is where I am lost. As seen by this example, we must identify the layers of the graph by name to pass our image data into -- http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/training-convolutional-neural-network-for-image-classification/.

So, what are the names of these layers? I suppose they something like "DecodeJpeg" and "/tower1/preditions/logits", but those are no better than guesses.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of mapping between operations before and after save/restore is by adding them to `collections`. Search for `tf.add_to_collection` and `tf.get_collection` in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/meta_graph. These examples save training_op and logits, but you can save your input placeholders as well.

If you cannot re-save the meta graph def and it does not have any collections, looking at node names and types (inputs are typically `placeholder` ops) might be the best you can do.